# How can I see if two Polygons overlap?

Tags: java, overlap, polygons

I need to check if two `java.awt.Polygon`s overlap, but I don't know how.

Comment: That's too bad. Got any code you can show us of what you've tried already?

Comment: I'm not a geometry expert, I wouldn't know how to find out whether points are inside the polygon or not. I haven't found this anywhere online.

Comment: "_I haven't found this anywhere online._" Then you haven't looked. I ran a quick Google search of "java polygons overlap" and found many examples, most of which link back to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Area area = new Area(poly1);
area.intersect(new Area(poly2));
return area.isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 2):

From a geometry perspective, there are conditions that are fulfilled by overlapping polygons.

1) If a segment in A crosses a segment in B, the polygons overlap.

2) If all vertices in B are inside A, or vice-versa, the polygons overlap.

3) If all vertices in A are also vertices of B, the polygons overlap.

Testing for (1) is fairly simple.  You just do a little algebra and brute force. If lines are parallel, they don't cross. If the lines are non-parallel, they intersect. If the point of intersection is within either segment, they cross. Maximum iterations is length of A * length of B.

Testing for (2) is a little more complex.  One method to tell if a point is inside a poly is this:  Pick a point that you know is outside of the poly, often a negative value for x,y works for this.  Then, draw a line from the reference point to the test point.  If it crosses an odd number of segments, it's inside. It if crosses an even number, or zero segments, it is outside.