# How to check whether there are polygons that overlap in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I am drawing, let's say 20 polygons at once in Kotlin by using GCP's Google map API.

How can I check whether there are polygons that overlap?

Thanks.

Comment: Does that question help? It depends on the object representation you use! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266184/how-can-i-see-if-two-polygons-overlap